# Perl in memory content writing in raw mode

Tags: perl, file-io, io

I am using perl 5.10.0 and trying to write content in a **memory buffer** in **raw mode**. But its not working. In the following code snippet I tried to compare the result between three scenarios

```
my ($s1, $s2);
open RAWF, '>:raw', \$s1;     #<-------  Opening in memory reference in raw mode
print RAWF 'Hello world in RAW MODE', "\n";

open FH, '>:raw', 'testfile.bin'; #<-------  Opening a file in raw mode
print FH 'Hello world in FILE', "\n";

open NORF, '>', \$s2;   #<-------  Opening in memory reference in normal mode
print NORF 'Hello world in NORMAL MODE', "\n";   

print $s1;    #<------ Doesnt print anything
print $s2;    #<------ Prints as expected
```

However, if I use perl 5.14.* then it works. Is that a limitation of perl 5.10.1? or it should be done in some other way to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this was a bug that was fixed in the Perl 5.12 timeframe.  See [perlbug #80764](https://rt.perl.org/rt3//Public/Bug/Display.html?id=80764) - even though the initial report/fix doesn't specifically mention your problem, this problem comes up [in the discussion on the bug](https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Ticket/Display.html?id=80764#txn-779794) and was rolled into those patches.